# Custom enumeration list Step 1, Step 2 etc

Tags: lists, enumerate

Any idea on how to create a list such that for each `\item` it creates a numbered `Step _ -`?
using the packages

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A code with `enumitem`: I define a `steps` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{label = Step \arabic*:}

\begin{document}

\begin{steps}
  \item first thing to do
  \item Second thing to do
  \item Third thing to do
\end{steps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to create a new environment, you can use the optional arguments of `enumerate`:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \arabic*:]
\item ...
.........
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: It also solved my problem. Any hints on how to control indentation or left margin space?

Comment: You have the `leftmargin=` key  (which sets the left margin of the text of each item). Yu also have the `wide=` key (in this case, the labels are left-aligned, whereas the default is that labels are right-aligned from the (list) left margin.

Comment: @Bernard How do you insert the ```leftmargin=``` option inside the enumerate environment? If I do something like ```\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2cm, label=Step \arabic*:]```, I get a "missing number, treated as 0" error.

Comment: Is it possible to add label to each caption?

Answer (score 15):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[Step 1:]
\item First thing to do
\item Second thing to do
\item Third thing to do
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @gernot when i  do this it is producing an error saying "missing    \item" any idea why?

Comment: @SamHarper Have you changed the code in any way? The code above should not give errors; it doesn't do on my computer.

Comment: i haven't used the enumerate package but iam using the following packages now stated in the question and i believe the amsmath should do it?

Comment: @SamHarper Well, you will have to use the `enumerate` package (or another one with the same functionality) if you want to have more flexibility in naming the items. If you remove `\usepackage{enumerate}` then naturally LaTeX will complain about a missing `\item` as soon as it encounters '[' after `\begin{enumerate}`.

Comment: @SamHarper If I **add** your packages above `\usepackage{enumerate}` everything works.

Comment: you are right and solved the issue above

Comment: @gernot It works but the items are not indented. How do I indent the items? Thanks.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe Not sure whether I understand correctly what you want but you can add some space in front of `Step`, e.g. by writing `\begin{enumerate}[\quad Step 1:]`. If you want to do something else, it's maybe better to ask a question yourself, with a detailed description of what it should look like.

Comment: @gernot `\ref{...}` yields Step 1:. How can I suppress the 'colon'?