# Indenting a custom "steps" environment (`enumitem` ) properly?

Tags: lists, enumitem

I was reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341183/custom-enumeration-list-step-1-step-2-etc) post on how to use a custom "steps" (list) environment in which each `\item` introduces a "Step " and increments the counter. However I do not know what the best way would be to indent the list so that it aligns with every other paragraph as demonstrated:

### Original

[image]

### What I want:

[image]

My code:

```latex
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{leftmargin=\parindent, label=\bfseries{Step \arabic*}:}

\begin{steps}
\item Start program.
\item Move value FFH to accumulator A.
\item Move value 01H to register B.
\item Move value 00H to register C.
\item Add contents of register B to accumulator.
\item If carry bit is 0, increment C, else continue.
\item Store accumulator data at address 8050H.
\item Move contents of register C to accumulator.
\item Store accumulator data at address 8051H.
\item End program.
\end{steps}
```

The two things that I want to do are:

1. align the list with all other paragraphs: I tried `\parindent` but it isnt working - I do not want to hardcode it to some value like `2cm`m etc.
2. if possible, align by the first letter `S` and not the `:` so that `Step 10` moves a little forward.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can add the key `wide=0pt` which forces the labels to be left-aligned, not right-aligned at the left margin of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness} {0.3pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=\parindent, label=Step \arabic*:, font=\bfseries}

    \begin{document}

\begin{steps}
\item Start program.
\item Move value FFH to accumulator A.
\item Move value 01H to register B.
\item Move value 00H to register C.
\item Add contents of register B to accumulator.
\item If carry bit is 0, increment C, else continue.
\item Store accumulator data at address 8050H.
\item Move contents of register C to accumulator.
\item Store accumulator data at address 8051H.
\item End program.
\end{steps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I am a little confused as to what `wide` and `leftmargin` are doing separately. I tried only `wide=0pt` and it does what I wanted, so what is the purpose of the `leftmargin`?

Comment: @FirstUser: In case the contents of an item is several lines long, its sets the left margin of these lines. If one only writes `wide=0pt`, the left margin is the same as for general text. Is it clearer?